# How to call a function within preg_replace()?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback, function-call

I've written a function that replaces certain patterns in a blog. For example when someone types: `:)` this function replaces it with a smiley emoticon.

However now I'm trying to do something special, but don't know how to accomplish it. I would like to parse a match to another function like so:

```
$pattern[] = "/\[ourl\](.*?)\[\/ourl\]/i";
$replace[] = "" . getOpenGraph("$1") . "";
$value = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
```

If someone uses [ourl]www.cnn.com[/ourl] this function will retrieve the OpenGraph information and return a specific HTML code.

However this does not work because it doesn't parse the `$1` to the function.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the hint u_mulder gave me I was able to pull it off

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: Or even [`preg_replace_callback_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, but it's php7 only.

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder that did the trick. Learned something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demonstration to show how to call `getOpenGraph()` and how the capture groups are passed as arguments without specifying them in the second parameter of `preg_replace_callback()`.

I modified the pattern delimiters so that the slash in the end tag doesn't need to be escaped.

```
function getOpenGraph($matches){
    return strrev($matches[1]);  // just reverse the string for effect
}

$input='Leading text [ourl]This is ourl-wrapped text[/ourl] trailing text';
$pattern='~\[ourl\](.*?)\[/ourl\]~i';
$output=preg_replace_callback($pattern,'getOpenGraph',$input);   
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
Leading text txet depparw-lruo si sihT trailing text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$content = "[ourl]test[/ourl]\n[link]www.example.com[/link]";
$regex = "/\[(.*)\](.*?)\[(\/.*)\]/i";

$result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
    return getOpenGraph($match[1], $match[2]);
}, $content);

function getOpenGraph($tag, $value) {
    return "$tag = $value";
}
echo $result;
```